# test a newly created branch without merging with master || git

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm a git/git-hub newbie,as I understand,we create branches to test new features and changes to our code without interfering with the original (master). I have a static index.html and build.sh and I created a branch called test_branch to perform my tests.

My question is can I test this branch without merging it with the master one? What's the point of branching if I have to merge it first before seeing any results?

I'm working on Ubuntu server, so no GUI or VS code is available.

Comment: What is preventing you from testing the branch?  How are you trying to test it, and what is happening to prevent it?

Comment: Well, when I edit the index.html file n the new branch I don't see the effects. I keep refreshing the page and nothing. I commited the changes on the new branch and pushed it to the remote repository.

Comment: Caching? Because Git is not at all in control over how you test stuff or what running given code does. Literally the *only* thing Git tracks is content. If you changed some content, Git will note it. If you change some code and something doesn't work as it should, that's completely out of Git's ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test your changes in your feature branch.  All you need is a test environment that is running off your `test_branch` branch.  In other words, you'll need to set up a test environment that is serving files from `test_branch` branch.

Answer (score 0):

From the clarification in comments, it sounds like you have some environment in which you manually perform tests - and you want that environment to be updated from what you put on the branch.  There are a few disconnects between that and how development/testing is typically set up (which probably explains why the people who rushed to answer before seeking said clarification aren't making much sense).

If you *really* want that single environment to run the most recent thing pushed - no matter what branch it was pushed on - then the answer is to configure your build/deployment process accordingly.  Since you haven't detailed how your build/deployment process works, I can't say how to do that.

I also can't say whether that solution makes much sense.  Usually an auto-deploy off of master is the production site, and if that's the case then deploying a branch to that site to test it would usually defeat an important part of the purpose of branching.

So a more typical approach is to have one environment targeted by the auto build/deploy from master, and one (or more) other environments that either (a) get auto built/deployed from other long-lived branches (like dev in a typical workflow), and/or (b) are targeted by manual build/deployment jobs that can be run against any branch.

Again the nuts and bolts of that depend on your build/deployment process.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand your question very well but anyway.

The fact that your files are in a branch or in another one doesn't have anything to do with seing results or not. If you want to see results, do it. Using branches is just a way to make your files perfect in the `test_branch`, see results as if they weren't in a branch or even in Git, make changes to improve your files and when it's done merge your `test_branch` in your `master` branch.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I tried this but nothing happened, I tried editing a line in index.html file.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you.Expectation of branching is exactly as you said perform any task without affecting the working code in master branch.When you create a new branch it is a clone from your master branch so you have all those file you find in master branch.You can do anything and test whether your new code is working fine.Then if you are okay with it and there is no conflicts you can merge your branch to the master branch.